# Compiling a full static executable in Visual Studio 2010 with boost library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, compilation, executable

I'm trying to compile a full independent static executable file with MS Visual C++ - Express.

I'm use the boost libraries, which are also compiled with static linking:

> b2 --toolset=msvc-10.0 --link=static runtime-link=static variant=release threading=multi

In Visual Studio I have these settings:

> General: MFC use static library
>
> VC++ Directories -> Include Directory: PATH TO BOOST FILES
>
> C/C++ -> Code Generation: Runtime Library Muthithreaded
>
> C/C++ -> Precompiled Header: Don't use
>
> Linker-> Input: Additional dependencies:  FULL PATH TO ALL USED BOOST LIB FILES 
>        (C:\boost_1_61_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_61.lib....)

I can compile a dynamicly linked executable, but if I try a static executable I receive this error:

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_61.lib'

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Properties should not be prefixed with `--`, so your build command should look something like:

> b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 link=static runtime-link=static variant=release threading=multi

Additionally, you seem to be building your project in debug mode, so the linker is looking for the debug versions of the boost libs.  It would probably be a good idea to build both the debug and release versions, so that you can build your project in both debug and release mode:

> b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 link=static runtime-link=static variant=debug,release threading=multi

That will generate two versions of each library, 'libboost_foo-vc100-mt-s-1_61.lib' and 'libboost_foo-vc100-mt-sgd-1_61.lib'.  The 's' version is the release lib, and the 'sgd' version is the debug lib.  See the [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) for exactly what each of those characters means.

---

EDIT:  After looking at your setup again, it looks like you've manually specified the path to all of the boost libs that you're using.  In addition to what I mentioned above about build properties, you should specify the library search path under `VC++ Directories -> Library Directories`.  In Visual Studio, boost will specify which libraries it needs using `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` preprocessor directives.  You can disable this behavior for a single library by defining `BOOST_<lib>_NO_LIB` before including its header, or for all libraries by defining `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`.

Comment: Right! I think I did it correct, but wrote it wrong here. Anyway, I will compile it again to be sure.

Comment: My preproccesor definition looks like that now:  WIN32
NDEBUG
_CONSOLE
BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
#pragma comment(lib, "boost_system")
#pragma comment(lib, "boost_regex")
#pragma comment(lib, "boost_date_time")
#pragma comment(lib, "boost_serialization")
#pragma comment(lib, "boost_thread")